# Предварительно выбранный автор в админке Django

Tags: python, django

Имеется вот такая модель:

```
class NewsContent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name = _('Author'))
    content = models.TextField(_('Content'))
```

Нужно, чтобы в админке django при создании нового новостного контента по умолчанию был выбран текущий пользователь в качестве автора.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Отвечаю на свой вопрос сам. В недрах django нашёл код куда можно внедриться без особых проблем, да и с доступом к request. Получилось очень даже красиво.

```
class NewsContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        field = super(NewsContentAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == "author":
            field.initial = kwargs["request"].user.id
        return field
```

Comment: cool, пометьте как правильный

Comment: хэшкод не позволяет собственный ответ отмечать правильным. Наверно это правильно.

Comment: @Antik Свой ответ можно ответить как правильный (появится галочка) через два дня после опубликования ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Создайте кастомную форму для своей модели и переопределите admin view для редактирования данной модели, в этом view словите request.user, который и передадите в форму как initial data (или передадите параметром в конструктор формы). Возможно, для такой мелкой задачи это решение тяжеловато, зато это документированная возможность (не костыль) и при переезде на более новые версии фреймворка у вас ничего "не поедет".
Как создать custom admin forms/views для cвоих моделей, подробно описано в [официальной документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/).

Answer (score 3):

Вот [здесь](http://bradjasper.com/blog/setting-default-values-in-django-admin-with-greasemonkey.html) пишут про js решение.

Answer (score 3):

Переопределяем метод [save_model класса ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) и добавляем там пользователя.

В вашем случае будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
class NewsContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку ответов нет, могу предложить или сделать все это на js, или сделать так что бы пользователь мог выбрать только себя:

если будет вот так

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name = _('Author'))
```

то в admins.py

```
class NewsContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Ващ класс для админки для данной модели """
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "author":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Users.objects.filter(pk = request.user.pk)
        return super(NewsContentAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```